# Reading a local file with typescript, and the 'this' object

Tags: typescript, this

I am writing a TypeScript browser application. I need to read the contents of an XML file, and store it in a class.  I am having issues with the 'this' object. Here is what I have so far:

```
class FileTools {
  text: string;

  readSingleFile(e) {
    var fileName = e.target.files[0];
    if (!fileName) {
        return;
    }
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = file => {
        var contents: any = file.target;
        this.text = contents.result; <== Issue here. 'this' is the filereader
    };
    reader.readAsText(fileName);
}

  start() {
    document.getElementById("file-input").addEventListener("change", this.readSingleFile, false);
  }
}

window.onload = () => {
  var tcx = new FileTools();
  tcx.start();
};
```

The HTML has a file selection box
    input type="file" id="file-input"

The issue is that when the file is loaded, using the 'this' points to the file reader, not to my class. If I add a 'self' variable first like this:

```
  readSingleFile(e) {
    var fileName = e.target.files[0];
    if (!fileName) {
        return;
    }
    var reader = new FileReader();
    var self = this;
    reader.onload = file => {
        var contents: any = file.target;
        self.text = contents.result; <== Issue here. 'this' is the filereader
    };
    reader.readAsText(fileName);
}
```

then self points to the input box (as that is the context of the outer method).

So the question is, how do I get the real 'this' object for the FileTools reference.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In ES6 and TypeScript even for class methods the regular function rules for this still apply.

In the **start** method you are sending a reference to the **readSingleFile** function as the callback for the change event.That function will later get called in the input field's context thus changing what **this** points to.

Try using an arrow function instead to preserve the same context.

```js
 start() {
   document.getElementById("file-input").addEventListener("change", e => {
     this.readSingleFile(e); // this should now be FileTools
   }, false);
 }
```

Comment: Thanks. Can someone explain, or point me to an explanation, why this solution works. why does the arrow function change the scope.

Comment: This might help clear some things. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work